# structure repetition error compiling C WinSock code in visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

I have been trying to compile C source code in  visual studio 2010. While compiling i am getting some errors like:

```
  1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winnt.h(4277): error C2040: 'CONTEXT' : '_CONTEXT' differs in levels of indirection from 'binding *'
  1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winuser.h(5341): error C2365: 'INPUT' : redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
  1>c:\documents and settings\xyz\desktop\abc\clause.h(72) : see declaration of 'INPUT'
  1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\sys/time.h(16): error C2011: 'timeval' : 'struct' type redefinition
  1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\WinSock2.h(176) : see declaration of 'timeval'
```

I searched for those error and but some hints that it is due to the change in order of the header files. But could not get the exact answer. May I know , How can I overcome this problem?

Following is the order of  header file inclusions.

```
 #include <WinSock2.h>  
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide (1) the contents of clause.h (at least all of the lines which have #include in them) and (2) show where clause.h occurs in the include order?  What is happening here is most likely that winsock.h is getting included before WinSock2.h  Windows.h does this by default, but the order in which your includes are stated above make it seem there's more to this than just that.

Comment: (Barring all that, try just putting #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN at the top of your source file and see if that fixes it.)

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - if you include `windows.h` explicitly with `winsock2.h` you have to add a `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` to make this work.

> For historical reasons, the Windows.h
>   header defaults to including the
>   Winsock.h header file for Windows
>   Sockets 1.1. The declarations in the
>   Winsock.h header file will conflict
>   with the declarations in the
>   Winsock2.h header file required by
>   Windows Sockets 2.0.  The WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN macro prevents the Winsock.h from being included by the Windows.h header.